# Read data matrix barcodes on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner

Is there any Open Source project I can use to read data matrix codes (not QR  codes, I know I can use ZXing project to read QR Codes) on iPhone? Any JAVA Open Source would also be helpful (I'll convert that into a web service and use on iPhone).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) also has a Data Matrix detector / decoder which may be good enough for your purposes. See `com.google.zxing.datamatrix` in `core/`.